# Dictionary of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, conditional-statements

I have a list and dictionary of tuples like this:

```
fruits=['apple','orange']

mydict={0:('apple', 12),
        1:('xyz',20),
        2:('orange',15)}
```

I want to be able to apply a condition on tuple item[0] such that if the value exists in the list 'fruits' then I want the dictionary to be updated as:

```
mydict={0:('apple', 12, 'f'),
        1:('tomato', 20, 'unknown'),
        2:('orange', 15, 'f')}
```

How can I achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `{i:(*v, 'f') if v[0] in set(fruits) else ('tomato', v[1], 'unknown') for i,v in mydict.items()}` better you use the set function outside the list comprehension like `fruits = set(fruits)` because I am not sure whether the set will be done at every iteration which is wastage.

Answer (score 4):

something like this

```
fruits = ['apple', 'orange']

data = {0: ('apple', 12),
        1: ('xyz', 20),
        2: ('orange', 15)}

for k, v in data.items():
    flag = v[0] in fruits
    data[k] = (v[0], v[1], 'f' if flag else 'unknown')
print(data)
```

output

```
{0: ('apple', 12, 'f'), 1: ('xyz', 20, 'unknown'), 2: ('orange', 15, 'f')}
```

Comment: But the OP required the original dict to be updated.

Comment: @quamrana - that is true. Lets here from OP if that is important for him/her or not. Anyway - I have modified the code.. so feel free to up vote :-)

Comment: We might have to wait for a long time. . .  so +1 in the meantime!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to **update** the existing dictionary, I would do this:

```
fruits = ['apple','orange']

mydict = {0:('apple', 12),
          1:('tomato', 20),  # <-- I changed this.
          2:('orange', 15)}

for i, (fruit, score) in mydict.items():
    tag = 'f' if fruit in fruits else 'unknown'
    mydict[i] = (fruit, score, tag)
```

After this, your dict `mydict` will look like:

`{0: ('apple', 12, 'f'), 1: ('tomato', 20, 'unknown'), 2: ('orange', 15, 'f')}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a dict comprehension:

```
fruits=['apple','orange']

mydict={0:('apple', 12),
        1:('xyz',20),
        2:('orange',15)}

res = {k: v + ('f',) if v[0] in fruits else v + ('unknown',) for (k,v) in mydict.items()}

print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by following code:

```
fruits=['apple','orange']

mydict={0:('apple', 12),
        1:('xyz',20),
        2:('orange',15)}

for key, tup in mydict.items():
    mydict[key] = tup + ('f',) if tup[0] in fruits else tup + ('unknown',)
    
print (mydict)
```

Output:

```
{0: ('apple', 12, 'f'), 1: ('xyz', 20, 'unknown'), 2: ('orange', 15, 'f')}
```